# setColorFilter shows a null object reference

Tags: android, android-drawable

I create a layout resource file named  btn.xml, it contains ImageView.
in main activity i inflate btn.xml in content_main.xml and i try to set background of inflated View. but it shows me : *Drawable.setColorFilter(int, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)' on a null object reference*

code java in mainActivity :

```
View v;
RelativeLayout rlt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    LayoutInflater myInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.btn,null,false);
    // Here is the probelm :
    v.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
    rlt = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlt);
    rlt.addView(v);
}
```

content_main.xml Layout :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.othma.tjkljklj.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:id="@+id/rlt">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

btn.xml layout Resource file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgv1"
        android:src="@drawable/continu" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i have edited the post

Comment: btn.xml has no background. Why do you expect getBackground to return something not null?

Comment: I'm new in android programmation, so what have i to do ? i don't want to change background in xml but in code , onClick

Comment: Can you respond me pleas e?

Comment: The problem, is that you have no background. So getting the background will obviously return a null. If you want to SET the background, use the appropriate accessor- example:  setBackgroundResource()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your *btn.xml* file as you see you did not set any drawable to your view(linearlayout), so you got a *null object reference* error.

***setColorFilter()*** method specify a *color* and *Porter-Duff mode* to be the color filter for  **drawable**.

For example; if you want to change imageview drawable(or any view drawable) color, you should use setColorFilter() method.

```
imageview.getDrawable().setColorFilter(color, mode);
```

if you want to change background color of your view, then you should use ***setBackgroundColor()*** method.

```
view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.anycolor));
```

Comment: thanks , it works but that's not realy the result i've looking for.

i want to make some effect on the VIEW to be shown in pressed mode , fore example when i press on the view it becomes more dark so that user will see that it is realy pressed....

with setColorFilter(int, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) on ImageView it does good work

Answer (score 0):

Your LinearLayout does not have any background.

You propably should Use **setBackgroundColor(int resid)** like this:

```
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
```

Note: It's lot safer to explicit cast your inflated view. Here is complete code:

```
LinearLayout v;
RelativeLayout rlt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    LayoutInflater myInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // Explicit Cast to LinearLayout
    v = (LinearLayout) myInflater.inflate(R.layout.btn,null,false);
    // setting background:
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));

    rlt = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlt);
    rlt.addView(v);
}
```

Comment: Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xff00ff00

Comment: `setBackgroundResource` takes an id as a parameter,  not arbitrary color